# Information/example on Unified Virtual Addressing (UVA) in CUDA

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia

I'm trying to understand the concept of Unified Virtual Addressing (UVA) in CUDA. I have two questions:

1. Is there any sample (psudo)code available that demonstrates this concept?
2. I read in the CUDA C Programming Guide that UVA can be used only with 64 bit operating systems. Why it is so?

Comment: The [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#unified-virtual-address-space) may be of interest.

Comment: Concerning your first question, have a look at the CUDA simpleP2P example.

Answer (score 7):

A [unified virtual address space](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#unified-virtual-address-space) combines the  pointer (values) and allocation mappings used in device code with the pointer (values) and allocation mappings used in host code into a single unified space.

> 1-Is there any sample (psudo)code available that demonstrate this concept?

One example of how this may be used is in the usage of the `cudaMemcpyDefault` [transfer kind specifier](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__TYPES.html#group__CUDART__TYPES_1g18fa99055ee694244a270e4d5101e95b), in place of `cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost` or `cudaMemcpyHostToDevice` in `cudaMemcpy` [operations](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g48efa06b81cc031b2aa6fdc2e9930741).

> 2-Also I read in the programming guide that it is associated only with 64 bit operating system. Why it is so?

A 32 bit machine has a maximum addressable space of 4 Gigabytes.  In modern GPUs (with perhaps multiple gigabytes of memory) and modern PCs (with perhaps multiple gigabytes of memory and I/O space) this is not conveniently enough space to have both the host and device memory spaces defined in it.