# Confusion about CUDA unified virtual memory

Tags: c++, c, cuda

I have some confusion about unified virtual memory.

The documentation behind the link (http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#unified-virtual-address-space) says it can be used when...

> When the application is run as a 64-bit process, a single address space is used for the host and all the devices of compute capability 2.0 and higher.

But this link (http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-requirements) says it needs:

> a GPU with SM architecture 3.0 or higher (Kepler class or newer)

Furthermore, the first link says that I can use `cudaHostAlloc`. The second one then uses `cudaMallocManaged`.

Are there 2 different things between this 'Unified' term or is the documentation just a bit incoherent?

Comment: UVA and UM/UVM are two different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are refering to Unified Virtual Address Space which is not the same as Unified memory which was introduced since CUDA 6.0 and for architecture 3.0 or higher and eliminates the need for explicit data transfer from host to device

[unified memory](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-unified-memory-programming-hd)

[unified memory2](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/unified-memory-in-cuda-6/)

You can check also:

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19186998/information-example-on-unified-virtual-addressing-uva-in-cuda) , [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891610/detection-if-a-pointer-is-pointing-in-the-device-or-host-in-cuda/14908262#14908262)

Comment: But what is the point of Unified Virtual Address Space, when I still need to copy my data manually? I do not see any advantage against "no Unified Virtual Address Space".

Comment: @Michael:Please check [this][1] and [this][2] . [1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29013903/confusion-about-cuda-unified-virtual-memory/29014309?noredirect=1#comment46332975_29014309 .[2]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19186998/information-example-on-unified-virtual-addressing-uva-in-cuda