# How can I pass an array of objects to a CUDA kernel, when each object has a pointer to another object

Tags: c++, cuda

```
class A 
{
  B *b;
}
```

Supose that I have an array of elements of Class A, and I want to send them to a CUDA kernel! Without the pointer inside it would be trivial, because I'll just need to call

```
cudaMalloc(&arrayA, sizeof(A) * numberof A elements).
```

In this situation if I just call cudaMalloc, what happens to memory pointed by *b pointer? It remains as a pointer to Host memory? I searched that I could pin memory on the host and access to it from the device, is it viable to pin *b pointed memory and access it from device (Access times)? Or if I should copy the entire b object to device memory and make *b as a reference to device memory?

Comment: you should copy the object indeed, have you any good reason of not doing it ?

Comment: I should copy the b object inside A object to device memory? I have nearly one million A objects!

Comment: is your B object distinct for every A object ? And what's a A object size compared to a B object size ?

Comment: B object is distinct for every A object! B object is 4 times larger

Comment: If B is conceptually a part of A, why is it a pointeur ? and not agregation ? Moreover, why is it ok to copy A to host, but not B ? ( I know I'm not answering your question here, but the understanding of WHY you need to do this is very important in order to give you an answer )

Comment: I think you are right! I could just agreate B object to A! But what will happen in this case if I just allocate A on device? Does b remains as a pointer to host? Thanks for the answer

Comment: well, you can't just use directly the original pointer to get to B on the host from the device, but I think that there's a system to request a virtual CUDA address which can be accessed from both HOST and device, but not directly using the original pointer, but for this I'll let someone with more knowledge answer (and YES it was your original question, but sometimes, the answer is to do otherwise because it would make more sense rather than adressing the technical problem directly)

Comment: look into CUDA Unified Virtual Addressing

Comment: seems that this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29013903/confusion-about-cuda-unified-virtual-memory could be interesting

Comment: Thank you all for helping me!